# How can I get Date in MM/DD/YY format from Timestamp

Tags: java, android

I want to get the Date in `MM/DD/YY` format from a timestamp.

I have used the below method but it does not gives proper output

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(1306249409));    
Log.d("Date--",""+cal.DAY_OF_MONTH);    
Log.d("Month--",""+cal.MONTH);    
Log.d("Year--",""+cal.YEAR);
```

But its gives the output like below

Date--5
Month--2
Year--1

The correct date is 24 May 2010 for Timestamp - 1306249409

Note - Timestamp is received by a webservice which is used in my application.

Comment: Does Android have SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: is that really 24 May 2010, not 2011?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Better Approach**

Simply Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date(timeStampMillisInLong));
```

---

**Mistake in your Approach**

`DAY_OF_MONTH` ,`MONTH`, .. etc are just constant int value used by `Calendar` class 
internally

You can get the date represented by `cal` by `cal.get(Calendar.DATE)`

Comment: Please never use lower-case `l` to indicate that the number is a literal `long`; always use upper-case `L`. The `l` looks too much like the digit `1`.

Answer (score 20):

Use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String time = sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 5):

**What's wrong:**

`Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`, `Calendar.MONTH` etc are static constants used to access those particular fields. (They will remain constant, no matter what `setTimeInMillis` you provide.)

---

**How to solve it:**

To get those particular fields you can use the [`.get(int field)`-method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29), like this:

```
Log.d("Month--",""+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

---

As others have pointed out there are more convenient methods for formatting a date for logging. You could use for instance the `SimpleDateFormat`, or, as I usually do when logging, a format-string and `String.format(formatStr, Calendar.getInstance())`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do change as per your answer but then I get the Month - 0 , Year - 1970 and Day - 01

Comment: @Mohit Kanada, some fields are 0-indexed. @Grzegorz Szpetkowski answer takes this into account. You're probably even better off using for instance `SimpleDateFormat` or the `String.format` method.

Answer (score 4):

```
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    String s = formatter.format(date);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"); // avoiding local time zone overhead
final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(utc);

// always use GregorianCalendar explicitly if you don't want be suprised with
// Japanese Imperial Calendar or something

cal.setTimeInMillis(1306249409L*1000); // input need to be in miliseconds

Log.d("Date--",""+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

Log.d("Month--",""+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1); // it starts from zero, add 1

Log.d("Year--",""+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 1):

Java uses the number of milliseconds since 1st January 1970 to represent times. If you compute the time represented by 1306249409 milliseconds, you'll discover that it's only 362 days, so your assumptions are wrong.

Moreover, `cal.DAY_OF_MONTH` holds a constant. Use `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` to get the day of month (same for other parts of the date).

Answer (score 0):

use `String.format` which is able to convert long (milliseconds) to date/time string in different formats:

```
    String str;
    long time = 1306249409 * 1000L;  // milliseconds
    str = String.format("%1$tm/%1$td/%1$ty", time);  // 05/24/11
    str = String.format("%tF", time);                // 2011-05-24 (ISO 8601)
    str = String.format("Date--%td", time);          // Date--24
    str = String.format("Month--%tm", time);         // Month--05
    str = String.format("Year--%ty", time);          // Year--11
```

documentation: [format string](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).